# How to download zip file without downloading entire directory path too? (PHP)

Tags: php, download, zip, document-root

I have the following zip download function:

```
$file='myStuff.zip';
function downloadZip($file){
  $file=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/uploads/'.$file;
   if (headers_sent()) {
    echo 'HTTP header already sent';
   } 
       else {
        if (!is_file($file)) {
            header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found');
            echo 'File not found';
        } else if (!is_readable($file)) {
            header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 403 Forbidden');
            echo 'File not readable';
        } else {
            header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 200 OK');
            header("Content-Type: application/zip");
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
            header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($file)."\"");
            readfile($file);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I call this function, I end up downloading not just myStuff.zip, but the complete directory path with all the folders. I'm on a Mac using XAMPP so this means I get the following:

```
/applications/xampp/htdocs/uploads/myStuff.zip
```

meaning i get a folder called applications with all the subfolders and then inside all of them I get myStuff.zip.

How can I just download `myStuff.zip` without its directories?

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php).

Comment: getting rid of `basename()` just re-adds the path info to the name of the download zip

Comment: Why don't you just retain the `$file` from the beginning?

Comment: Try Wireshark if you can monitor what's actually going out.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, i'm not sure what you mean about retaining the file from the beginning. What I'd like to have is to be able to download a zip from at any point from just clicking a link.

Comment: I don't know if you need the `"` around the `filename=` attribute, either. Ok, and I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I answered my own question by using the code in this link: http://www.travisberry.com/2010/09/use-php-to-zip-folders-for-download/

Here's the PHP:

```
<?php
//Get the directory to zip
$filename_no_ext= $_GET['directtozip'];

// we deliver a zip file
header("Content-Type: archive/zip");

// filename for the browser to save the zip file
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename_no_ext".".zip");

// get a tmp name for the .zip
$tmp_zip = tempnam ("tmp", "tempname") . ".zip";

//change directory so the zip file doesnt have a tree structure in it.
chdir('user_uploads/'.$_GET['directtozip']);

// zip the stuff (dir and all in there) into the tmp_zip file
exec('zip '.$tmp_zip.' *');

// calc the length of the zip. it is needed for the progress bar of the browser
$filesize = filesize($tmp_zip);
header("Content-Length: $filesize");

// deliver the zip file
$fp = fopen("$tmp_zip","r");
echo fpassthru($fp);

// clean up the tmp zip file
unlink($tmp_zip);
?>
```

and the HTML:

```
<a href="zip_folders.php?directtozip=THE USERS DIRECTORY">Download All As Zip</a>
```

The key step in getting rid of the directory structure appears to be the `chdir()`. It is also worth noting that the script in this answer makes the zip file on the fly rather than trying to retrieve a previously zipped file as I did in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
readfile(basename($file));
```

Comment: -@circusrob, thanks now when I click on the downloaded file, it opens a `myStuff.zip.cpgz` file. Meaning, it doesn't show the contents of myStuff. Seems closer to right, but still something wrong...

Comment: You need to clean the buffer and flush the buffer before reading. eg. `ob_clean(); flush(); readfile(basename($file)); exit;`.

Comment: didn't affect the result, still the same as just having `readfile(basename($file));`

Comment: Apparently your browser might be caching. Please refer to this example at the [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) site. Try enforcing cache control and try again.

Comment: still getting `myStuff.zip.cpgz` after clicking on `myStuff.zip`. Just cut/pasted the php.net code: `        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);`

Comment: This is quite unfortunate but I am thinking the zip file itself might be corrupt or it has something to do with memory. Please check your php.ini directives for `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` if your file size falls within those range.

Comment: the file is only 361kb and my `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize= 128M`, yeah this is frustrating...